# Flask/Python 3 : How to parse an url which contain associative array?

Tags: python, url, flask

i would like to get from this url an array of tuple which contain all the filter and the same for the page.

```
filter = [('product_type', 'audio'),  ('feature_configuration_menu' , 'volume')]
```

My URL :

```
curl -X GET 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/my_resource?filter[product_type]=audio&filter[feature_configuration_menu]=volume&page[number]=1&page[offset]=5
```

I using the framework flask, python 3

```
@api.route('/my_resource', methods=['GET'])
def my_resource():
   # From `request.args` I would like this :
   # filter = [('product_type', 'audio'),  ('feature_configuration_menu' , 'volume')]

   return jsonify({'key': 'value'})
```

Thank you

in PHP it's so easy $_GET['filter'] and it give you an array('product_type' => 'audio', 'feature_configuration_menu' => 'volume'). Why so difficult on Python !?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if flask can properly handle your URL. 
Event if it's not perfect I would do it like that

Your URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/my_resource?filter=product_type-audio&filter=feature_configuration_menu-volume&page=number-1&page=offset-5
```

The WS:

```
@app.route('/my_resource', methods=['GET'])
def my_resource():
    # From `request.args` I would like this :
    # filter = [('product_type', 'audio'),  ('feature_configuration_menu' , 'volume')]

    filter = [tuple(filter.split('-')) for filter in request.args.getlist('filter')]

    return jsonify(filter)
```